# Powershell - UNIX ANSI file encoding being changed and genterating CRLF

Tags: unix, powershell, encoding, newline

I am using Powershell in windows to replace a '£' with a '$' in a file generated in Unix. The problem is that the output file has CRLF at the end of each line rather than LF which it originally had. When I look at the original file in Notepad++ the status bar tells me it is Unix ANSI, I want to keep this format and have LF at the end of each line.
I have tried all the encoding options with no success, I have also tried Set-Content instead od Out-File. My code is:

```
$old = '£'
$new = '$'
$encoding = 'UTF8'
(Get-Content $fileInfo.FullName) | % {$_ -replace $old, $new} | Out-File -filepath $fileInfo.FullName -Encoding $encoding
```

Thanks for any help
Jamie

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852682/convert-file-from-windows-to-unix-through-powershell-or-batch

Answer (score 5):

@Keith Hill made a cmdlet for this `ConvertTo-UnixLineEnding` you can find it in the  [Powershell Community Extension](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)

Comment: you are welcome please remember to mark post as answered if it has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is a very old question now but I stumbled across it when I encountered a similar issue and thought I would share what worked for me.  This may help other coders in future without the need for a third party cmdlet.

When reading in the Unix format file, that is with LF line terminators, rather than the CRLF Windows style line terminators, simply use the **-Raw** parameter after the filename in your **Get-Content** command then output with encoding type of **STRING**, although UTF8 encoding may have the same result STRING worked for my requirements.

My specific command that I had issue with was reading in a template file, replacing some variables then outputting to a new file.  The original template is Unix style, but the output was coming out Windows style until adding the -Raw parameter as follows. Note that this is a powershell command I used called from a batch file, hence its formatting.

```
powershell -Command "get-content master.template -Raw | %%{$_ -replace \"@MASTERIP@\",\"%MASTERIP%\"} | %%{$_ -replace \"@SLAVEIP@\",\"%SLAVEIP%\"} | set-content %MYFILENAME%-%MASTERIP%.cfg -Encoding STRING"
```

I use Notepad++ to check the formatting of the resulting file and this did the trick in my case.